# Driver BSODs (Minidump inside)

Tags: windows, windows-7, bsod, dump, minidumps

I have been attempting to troubleshoots some BSODs on an older machine running Windows 7. It first generated a corrupted dump that only gave me the following info:

```
DRIVER_CORRUPTED_EXPOOL (c5)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is
caused by drivers that have corrupted the system pool.  Run the driver
verifier against any new (or suspect) drivers, and if that doesn't turn up
the culprit, then use gflags to enable special pool.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000000000b0, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
Arg4: fffff8000a5f3d03, address which referenced memory
```

I then set the machine to generate a minidump instead. A few days later, it crashed with a MULTIPLE_IRP_COMPLETE_REQUESTS (44). I would like to know if anyone can tell me more about this error from the [minidump](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EG7JuzyXODZrbZh7rMBwjy2zeZRveQhv/view?usp=share_link). Thank you in advance.

Comment: The minidump is a complete `.dmp` file, better posted online (OneDrive, Dropbox etc).

Comment: If you open the .dmp file with WhoCrashed, it should tell you what the culprit is.

Comment: @harrymc added link to dmp file

Comment: @spikey_richie no luck.

Answer (score 2):

The analysis of the `.dmp` file shows that the crash happens within the
driver `USBPORT.SYS`.

The name makes it obvious that some USB device is misbehaving or that
some USB port is broken.
Many problem types are possible, for example the device/port causing
power spikes.

I suggest to disconnect all USB devices, then add them back slowly
one at a time, until the bad device or port is found.

If this is happening when no USB devices are connected, then the
problem is surely with a port or the USB controller.
In this case, the repair-shop is the best solution.

Comment: I think it might be happening while a single USB device is connected: a USB dongle for a bluetooth + mouse combo to connect to. Which seems weird. The fact that the first dump was corrupted is also odd, but perhaps it's just because it was a default (non-mini) dump.

Comment: Try : (1) Another USB port (if you have one), (2) Connecting via a USB hub (if you have one), (3) On another computer.